# sudo apt-get update failure 14.04 LTS

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, synaptics

I have tried from several PC's. All the places we only get three lines of error

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_i18n_Translation-en%5fIN
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

We are not able to install any packages or do any updates. We are totally stuck. I have goggled but could not find any appropriate solution.

Is there any way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Run `sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` and run `sudo apt-get update` again